# Python- How to store values in if condition to a list with append

Tags: python, list, append

here's the code:

```
test('a')
test('b')
test('c')

def test(value):
    if (value == 'a'):
        print(value)
    if (value == 'b'):
        print(value)
    if (value == 'c'):
        print(value)
    r = []
    r.append(value)
    print('r=', r)
```

The output will be:

```
a
r= ['a']
b
r= ['b']
c
r= ['c']
```

I need the list 'r' stores a , b and c. Something like this:

```
r=['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Is that possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the issue here, exactly? You want `r=['a', 'b', 'c']`, doesn't that work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this change,

```
r = []
def test(value):
    if (value == 'a'):
        print(value)
    if (value == 'b'):
        print(value)
    if (value == 'c'):
        print(value)
    global r
    r.append(value)
    print('r=', r)
```

You are clearing list r everytime you run function.
The way to solve this is to have list at global level and append your parameters to it through function

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you!

Comment: what is the need for so many if conditions? why not make a list of all the items you want to check and just have 1 condition that says `if value in list_values: print(value)`

Comment: There is a possibility that it is a sample code. And real code would be something different.

Comment: I added my solution at the bottom if the OP still needs a more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

You need make the `r` outside of your `test function`.
Like this:

```py
r = []
test('a')
test('b')
test('c')

def test(value):
    if (value == 'a'):
        print(value)
    elif (value == 'b'):
        print(value)
    elif (value == 'c'):
        print(value)
    r.append(value)
    print('r=', r)
```

The reason why you can't get that you expected with your code:
Each run the `test`  function, the `r` will be clear.
So, you need in outside to create the `r`, like above code.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have so many if statement and still produces the expected result.

```
value_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
r = []

def test(value):
    if value in value_list:
        print(value)
        r.append(value)
    return r


for value in value_list:
    print('r={}'.format(test(value)))
```

## Output

```
a
r=['a']
b
r=['a', 'b']
c
r=['a', 'b', 'c']
```

## Note

Right now the for loop cycles through all the values in the list and thus the if statement is always true. If you want otherwise you can replace the for loop with:

```
test('a')
print('r={}'.format(r))
test('d') # Not in "value_list"
print('r={}'.format(r))
test('c')
print('r={}'.format(r))
```

## Second Output:

```
a
r=['a']
r=['a']
c
r=['a', 'c']
```

As you can see this ignores values not in `value_list`.

Answer (score -1):

Or, you can make them as `Class`.

```py
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.r = []

    def test(self, value):
        if value == 'a':
            print(value)
        elif value == 'b':
            print(value)
        elif value == 'c':
            print(value)
        self.r.append(value)
        return self.r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    print(t.test('a'))  # a
    print(t.test('b'))  # a, b
    print(t.test('c'))  # a, b, c
```